# How are paths calculated in PHP - Why are files in the current directory ignored?

Tags: php

Update:

The index.php file here:

```
/public_html/d/index.php
```

includes:

```
/public_html/d/core/source/class.File1.php
```

This Class.File1.php here has this include written like this:

```
include 'class.File2.php';
```

Naturally I put `class.File2.php` in the same directory as class.File1.php as noted above.

```
/public_html/d/core/source/class.File2.php
```

However,

It actually includes this file: ( notice the missing `/d/` )

```
/public_html/core/source/class.File2.php
```

Not sure why it doesn't use the file that is in the current directory.

But here are some possibilities.

Entry from a user requesting the page comes in to: ( user types `www.host.com/d` )

```
/public_html/d/
```

This has an include to: ( which works fine, I tested it )

```
/public_html/d/core/source/class.File1.php
```

However the include in that file is where things break as noted above:

```
include "class.File2.php"
```

The only thing that makes sense...is that includes are using some sort of internal constant like

```
ROOT
```

or

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

but I still can't figure out why it would ignore the `/d/` but figure out the rest.

Comment: Check the include path with get_include_path() and if needed complete it with set_include_path()

Comment: inlcude_path is B.s...does not follow this in my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) anywhere in your app? Perhaps that could be the cause of your problem. By doing that you are specifying a list of directories where the require, include, fopen(), file(), readfile() and file_get_contents() functions look for files first.

As an alternative I suggest you define the absolute path to avoid problems.
Write this on your `/public_html/d/core/source/class.File1.php`

```
// This if you are using PHP >= 5.3
include(__DIR__ . '/class.File2.php');

// Or this if you dont have the magic constant __DIR__ available
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.File2.php');
```

`__FILE__` and `__DIR__` are magic constants. `__FILE__` is a constant that has the absulute path to that specific file. And `__DIR__` is the absulte path to the directory where that file is. You can even test them by doing `echo __FILE__;` or `echo __DIR__;`

You can read more about them here http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: No I do not use set_include_path();

Comment: Well the include path is for internal PHP libraries.  Here is what I'm getting - .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

Comment: This works where getcwd() fails....getcwd() always returns the same dir no matter where I'm at.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried including with a relative path?

```
include './class.File2.php';
```

Is class.File1.php itself included by some other script?

Comment: yeah but is class.File1.php included by some other file?

I'm thinking that the path may be derived from the path of the file that includes class.File1.php.

Comment: index.php calls it from host.com/d

Comment: I'll update it...there is something going on with the include path I think...http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: You may want to check the ini_get('include_path') (or get_include_path())

Comment: okay i was just going to suggest what mpratt wrote as well... you should try that as well.

Comment: Well the include path is for internal PHP libraries.  Here is what I'm getting - .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php

Comment: if all failed you can try:
    substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], "/")) . "/class.File2.php";
and include that

Answer (score 0):

- `getcwd()` always returns the same path no matter what file it is located in ( on my system ).  A Bug in my opinion.
- ( On my system ) PHP found another file in a path not specified in the include list or in the current directory.  This is a bug in my opinion.
- On my system, if you don't want to use absolute paths...the only way I've found to use relative paths is `dirname(__FILE__);` to prepend where you want to go.
- . or ./ prepending the file did not work either....

Comment: Needle in a haystack to figure this out.