# How do I change where PHP looks for user defined includes?

Tags: php

I'm about to go and change all my includes to use get current working directory to specify where to look.

```
getcwd()
```

because PHP does not look in the current directory as I thought it would.

Is there a way to change this behavior so my code is not littered with `getcwd()` everywhere?

A way to tell the inlcude function to look in the directory in which it itself is located.

I thought out of common sense it would do this but it does not.

Comment: You have asked 3 times the same related question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739002/how-are-paths-calculated-in-php-why-are-files-in-the-current-directory-ignored), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739813/php-can-not-find-my-include) and now this one in a little less than an hour). Perhaps if you go back to those questions, give us more details and post the full codes of both your files, we can give you better help... And no I dont think its a PHP bug.

Comment: It also appears you only cursorily skim the given answers. Below you are just ignoring the link to the manual and then go on to comment gibberish. That's not how problems are solved best.

Answer (score 1):

Set your [`include_path` in PHP.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Or, use `set_include_path()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: @CS_2013, Sure, see:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php#108084

Comment: @CS_2013, What are you talking about?  Where did you get that path?  Yes, it is very likely that is your current include path.  And, what do you mean it's another language?  I gave you a link to a PHP page... are you not doing this in PHP?  Your questions ays you are.

Comment: @CS_2013, Yes, and why should they?  You haven't added anything to that default include path yet.  Isn't that what you are asking?  Did I not give you two methods for doing so?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php  *"Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing. The include construct will emit a warning if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit a fatal error."*

Comment: @CS_2013, Unbelievable... now you are disputing a direct quote from the PHP documentation on a function that hasn't changed in years.  You are too stubborn to deserve help from anyone here.  I hope nobody wastes any time more time on you.  Your chosen path of ignorance is disappointing.  Don't bother posting here again.  Posts like yours are not welcome.