# What is the relation between getcwd() and get_include_path()?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change where PHP looks for user defined includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740582/how-do-i-change-where-php-looks-for-user-defined-includes)

```
getcwd()
```

returns

/home/core/public_html/d

and

```
get_include_path()
```

returns

:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php.

How do I set the include path?

Comment: -1 for spamming us with the same question over and over.

Comment: Once again. You have asked 4 times the same related question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739002/how-are-paths-calculated-in-php-why-are-files-in-the-current-directory-ignored), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739813/php-can-not-find-my-include), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740582/how-do-i-change-where-php-looks-for-user-defined-includes) and now this one in less than an hour). Perhaps if you go back to those questions,giveusmoredetails,post the full codes of both your files,we can give you better help. I understand the desperation, but come on man!

Comment: The question isn't why PHP does not conform to your expectations. The queston is why CS_2013 doesn't bother to look into the manual, which explains that very thing. And all the "related questions" isn't due to people giving you bad explanations. It's caused by your unwillingness to expand on your riddle questions.

Comment: To get higher quality answers, write a [higher quality question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) by including [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that is complete yet concise, including e.g. HTML source, SQL statements or table defintions, and preferrably some sample input and output data.
See also [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [HelpOverflow](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help2)

Comment: If you remover your answer I can delete this post.

Comment: That's why they call everything magic something....how did it find my file.....oh yea...that magic dragon got it!

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation.  The current working directory has nothing to do with the include path.

To set your include path, follow the two methods I already posted on your other question:  [How do I change where PHP looks for user defined includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740582/how-do-i-change-where-php-looks-for-user-defined-includes)